# Android - Remove Place Autocomplete Search Bar from Action Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-location

I am using `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` in my application. Its working fine, but the problem is that I doesn't want to have the place autocomplete search in my action bar. Insted I want to use it like an `EditText` below the action bar.

I want to use the full screen mode, but want to remove the search for places from the action bar.

This is my full `activity.xml` code:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="example.fragmentsample.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCurrentLocation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:onClick="fncGetCurrentLocation"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_current_location"
        android:text="Detect My Location"
        android:backgroundTint="#FF0000"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCurrentLocation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblCurrentLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the code for that, I am using Google Place Autocomplete Full Screen Mode:

```
try {
            Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN).build(this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        }
```

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the code of your `XML`

Comment: @AjilO. Yes I made the edit, its now added.

Comment: And where are you placing this fragment?

Comment: @AjilO. I have pasted my full xml code

Comment: Strange. It should not appear in the action bar at all. It should appear right below the `button`. Was that not what you wanted?

Comment: @AjilO. Exactly! But this is not working at all.